# redirect URL after Change the language in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm Search for redirect URL to Homepage after Change the language

Because I do not want to show URL language when click on image in the address bar

Example:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/?do=change&lang=en"><img src="images/en.png" alt="en" border="0"></a>

redirect http://www.mysite.com/?do=change&lang=en to http://www.mysite.com/
```

I have no experience Javascript

So one can explain how I do this

Comment: why don't you redirect it in your controller action directly after change language?

Comment: If you are looking to not show the "?do=change&lang=en" in the address bar, why not just have a HTTP redirect on that page (using PHP) or use cookies which can be done using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.replace()`.

`window.location.replace("http://www.mysite.com/");`

How you manage when the redirect occurs is up to you.